# block status before "processed"

Tags: debug

Solana's API initially supports retrieving blocks in the processed state, but processed blocks already represent the state after collecting votes. Is it possible to view the timestamp after the execution of transactions in a block but before the collection of votes through logs? Does the client provide any logs as hints after the completion of all transactions in a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `processed`, you're actually hitting the current working bank, so there's no consensus on that block just yet.

If you want to know when a block is done being processed on a node, you'll want to look at the "replay" stage metrics. "Replay" is when a node runs transactions on its state in order to produce the bankhash that it eventually uses to vote.

There are loads of datapoints during replay, so you can look through https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/99760e519ad7ba55f7b67d155e63e7f697c223b0/core/src/replay_stage.rs#L367 and see which might be most useful to you.

And keep in mind that votes are all transactions that are included in blocks, so you can simply look through the vote transactions in subsequent blocks to see when they're included later on!

Answer (score 1):

There is the Dragon Mouth plugin https://github.com/rpcpool/yellowstone-grpc which lets you get processed transactions as soon as they are processed by the validator. So you can get mid block transaction updates. You can get the process confirmation as soon as 150ms.
Helius and triton are implementing this already, so if you use a web socket connection and use one of their rpcs you will be able to use this easily.